# QuantLib: ImportError: DLL load failed:

Tags: quantlib

I intalled quantlib using "pip install QuantLib" and now I'm getting the below error.  I'm using windows 10 and Spyder IDE.  I don't see any dll file called _QuantLib, only _QuantLib.cp37-win_amd64.pyd.

File "C:\Conda\lib\site-packages\QuantLib\QuantLib.py", line 13, in 
from . import _QuantLib

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Can you try `pip freeze` to see which version you have? I recommend uninstalling, and making sure you don't have QuantLib-Python installed as well, then reinstall

Comment: Yes, I had both installed QuantLib-Python 1.18 and QuantLib 1.2.  I uninstalled QuantLib-Python but i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Which version/versions of python do you have installed, maybe they are clashing? Can you try 'which python' and 'which python3' (or Windows equivalent) to see what is running? Or I guess your IDE will have a box somewhere that tells you which python interpretor it is using?

Comment: I ran dependency walker and it determined I was missing vcruntime140_1.dll so I copied it from another folder into windows/system32 and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with QuantLib 1.2. Downgrading to 1.19 solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of the MSVC redistributable, that error usually occurs when the QuantLib binaries load and can't find the right version of MSVC runtime